How to create WCS 2.0.1 GetCoverage request using OWSLib?
I have access to a locally deployed GeoServer with enabled WCS 2.0.1.
I connect to the service by calling
from owslib.wcs import WebCoverageService

wcs = WebCoverageService(
    url='https://example.com/geoserver/ows',
    version='2.0.1',
    timeout=5,
)

I try to retrieve a specific Coverage by its coverageId by using
geotiff_data = wcs.getCoverage(identifier=[wcs['example_coverage'].id],
    subsets=[
        ('E',455985.7, 5428782.4),
        ('N',457001.0, 5429661.2)
        ],
    format='geotiff',
    #format='image/tiff',
    crs='EPSG:32632',
    width=200, height=200
)

where

example_coverage is the `coverageId
format is retrieved by checking the supportedFormats with geotiff defined as image/tiff;application=geotiff (here there are other formats, which I've also tried)
crs is the CRS with a value retrieved by manually inspecting the DescribeCoverage request results

I get an exception
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)

If I manually create a URL and call it in my web browser, I can download the GeoTIFF without any issues.
Example:
https://example.com/geoserver/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&coverageid=example_coverage&subset=E,http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/32632(455985.7,457001.0)&subset=N,http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/32632(5428782.4,5429661.2)

The axis labels I have retrieved from the DescribeCoverage's gml:Envelope:
<gml:Envelope srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/32632" axisLabels="E N" uomLabels="m m" srsDimension="2">
    <gml:lowerCorner>441425.2905999996 5414623.855999999</gml:lowerCorner>
    <gml:upperCorner>472044.89059999964 5445350.455999999</gml:upperCorner>
</gml:Envelope>

The OWSLib documentation on WCS is rather poor and I had to dig through its codebase in order to figure many things out. I was unable to find any help, especially in wcsBase.py and wcs201.py.

does an HTTP (port 80) request work?

@nmtoken It's not working (but HTTP in the web browser is). However, I did notice that I am still getting HTTPSConnectionPool error even though the URL is HTTP. I fear that OWSLib is doing something internally and overriding the URL.
Since I am greatly restrained by time I will just to a raw HTTP request for now but the issue remains unresolved.

does the GetCapabilities response document when using HTTP have an HTTPS URL for the operations

I have access to both (with and without SSL). See my "answer" below. timeout is the issue here.

I decided to replace OWSLib (using requests internally) with httpx and xml.etree.ElementTree to have more control (httpx supports async calls) and also to analyze the issue.
However, I encountered the very same issue there too. It appears that the requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout error occurs whenever the response took too long to read. This happens both with httpx.get() as well as httpx.stream(), the latter being intended for large volumes of data.
A way to fix it is to adjust the timeout, which, at least for WCS 2.0.1 is 30 (seconds) as documented in the source code of the base class. Depending on the size of the coverage (determined by the size of the bounding box, the quality of the data being retrieved (raw vs scaled and interpolated), number of bands in the data etc.) you may be downloading tens if not hundreds of megabytes or even more.
Setting timeout to None at least for httpx disables it, which may lead to an infinite waiting of course.
